# VBA code for mail.envelope throwing error

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a code for mail.envelope, however it is throwing me an error as below,

> "Method Introduction of Object ImSOmailenvelopeVB failed"

The code works fine for some users but throws the error for some on the code line, `.Introduction = Sheet3.Range("D2")`

If i remove the introduction code line then it works fine for all.

Can someone please help me out with this error

Comment: To reproduce the error, we will need the full code or the minimal reproducible version of it.

Comment: A shot in the dark... What happens when you do a `wb.Save: DoEvents` before initiating `.MailEnvelope` where `wb` is the workbook you are working with?

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
 
'Send Email through Outlook
 
With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope

.Introduction = Sheet3.Range("D2")
 
With .Item

.To = R
.CC = S
.BCC = T
.Subject = Sheet3.Range("D1") & " - " & company_name
.Send

End With

End With

Comment: @SiddharthRout Tried doing the wb.save but it still throws the same error

Comment: What is the value of `Sheet3.Range("D2")` What happens when you pass a string say `.Introduction = "Anup"` ?

Comment: Yes, its working as suggested by you. Any idea why? I wanted to keep the introduction part flexible that the users can edit and so had given the reference to Sheet3.Range("D2"). It had nothing but text

Comment: Now Try `.Introduction = Sheet3.Range("D2").Value`

Comment: Its working with .value as well. Cool thank you so much. Can you please let me know the reason for the same?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Can you please help me out with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57393211/vba-runtime-error-why-am-i-getting-an-error-while-sending-mail-through-outlook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the value of Sheet3.Range("D2") What happens when you pass a string say .Introduction = "Anup" ? – Siddharth Rout 22 mins ago    Delete
>
> Yes, its working as suggested by you. Any idea why? I wanted to keep the introduction part flexible that the users can edit and so had given the reference to Sheet3.Range("D2"). It had nothing but text – Anup Patil 4 mins ago
>
> Now Try .Introduction = Sheet3.Range("D2").Value – Siddharth Rout 8 mins ago
>
> Its working with .value as well. Cool thank you so much. Can you please let me know the reason for the same? – Anup Patil 18 secs ago

The default property of `.Range` is `.Value` when you do not specify it in such cases. In your case it is not picking that default property. Most probably it is picking it up as a `Range`. Hence it is a good practice to fully specify the code.

Changing

```
.Introduction = Sheet3.Range("D2")
```

to

```
.Introduction = Sheet3.Range("D2").Value
```

will help.