# VBA runtime error : Why am i getting an error while sending mail through outlook using mailenvelope

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code for sending multiple emails on one click to several email id's. The code works absolutely fine if the data is limited, however if the my data sheet contains large amount of data then it throws a run time error as below:

> "Run-time error '-2147417856 (80010100)':

The operation failed because of network or other communication problems. Verify your connection and try again."

Not sure why this happens. I have to then delete the data for the emails already sent and again start the macro and it again throws an error.

Can someone please help regarding this error

```
With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
    .Introduction = Sheet3.Range("D2").Value

    With .Item
        .To = R
        .CC = S
        .BCC = T
        .Subject = Sheet3.Range("D1") & " - " & company_name
        .Send
    End With
End With
```

I expect the code to run normally irrespective of the data i put in because i have not given any specific range in my coding

Comment: What happens when you put a `DoEvents` after the line `.Send`?

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks a ton for solving my query with your quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding DoEvents after the .send line solves the issue